# AWS Lambda function is not updating in basic test environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to set up a very basic AWS Lambda script, but I struggle to get the AWS Lambda `Test` functionality to recognize the changes I make.

To setup the simplest possible test, I created a new AWS Lambda function for Python 3.7. I then make a simple change in the code as below, add a test output and run Test:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('I changed this text')
    }
```

I've verified that `Version:` is set to `$LATEST` - yet when I run the test, there is no change in my output - it keeps returning the original code output. Further, if I try to export the function, I get the original code - not my updated code above (despite having saved it).

I realize this seems very basic, but I wanted to check if others have experienced this as well.

Comment: You deployed the change?

Comment: If you're updating in the console have you clicked `Save`?

Comment: I did click `Save` - I tried doing so both via `File/Save`, `Ctrl + S`. If I hit `Deploy` and then `Test` I get the updated result - but I would expect that it would be possible to test changes without deploying

Comment: I'm not sure what's the official expected behavior, but in my case I gotta hit deploy.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Based on feedback, it seems hitting `Deploy` is required in order to be able to test the updated function

additional:
Deploy updates the code the test runs against.

However, if you want to test different inputs to the same code then you can create a test and invoke it without deploying. See the hello world template for how to pass the input.

Answer (score 7):

Even with hitting `deploy`, there's a definite delay. Try adding a `print` statement and hitting deploy and then testing. This will show that it often doesn't accept the new code right away. EXTREMELY frustrating for debugging. I have to literally refresh my lambda console page to get the changes to take.